# If a 10-digit number 2094x843y2 is divisible by 88, then the value of (5x— 7y) for the largest possible value of x, is:

Tags: divisibility

options

> 3,5,2,6

my take

```
3y2 is divisible by 8 if y = 1 or 5 or 9

If y = 1, then

2094x84312 is divisible by 11 if x = 1

If y = 5, then

2094x84352 is divisible by 11 if x = 8

 5x – 7y

If y = 9, then

2094x84392 is divisible by 11 if x = 4    

For the largest possible value of x if x = 8 and y = 9

(5x – 7y) = 5 × 8 – 7 × 9 = 40 – 63 = -23
```

where am i wrong here ?

Comment: you should use $y = 5$ and not $y =9$, when calculating $5x-7y$.... as when x = 8 , y= 5... so $5*8-7*5 = 5 $. this is because they have asked the value of y when x is the biggest. not the biggest values possible for both x,y

Comment: can we use y = 1 then ? why are we particularly taking 5 ?

Comment: Hi there, in your calculations you computed that x = 8 is the largest and this takes place when y = 5. So when you are computing 5x-7y, you need to take the value of y corresponding to x, which in this case is 5 and not (1 or 9)....

Comment: oh ok that makes sense thanks for clearing that up ! i am weak in maths so i dont really get it very quickly !

Comment: Please delete the question now that all is clear, since it boils down to an oversight, so the question will not be useful to others (and may make browsingsearch results more difficult).